# Calling MATLAB from Visual Studio in a loop and returning the result from MATLAB simulation through each iteration

Tags: matlab, visual-studio

I am trying to invoke matlab from a loop in Visual Studio and run the simulation in MATLAB through each iteration. I want the result of the simulation in MATLAB to be passed back to visula studio using engGetVariable. However, it seems that I can not invoke the MATLAB for second iteration and I only get one result back from the MATLAB.

```
void matlab::matlab_ex(char* directory) {
Engine *ep=0;
//ep = engOpen(NULL);
double resultc[256];
double *presultc;
presultc = resultc;
char buffer[256];
char cmd[256];


const int arraysize1 = 9;

int i = 0;
double d=0;
ofstream myfile;

double samplerate[arraysize1] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };
double length[arraysize1] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };

mxArray* SAMPLE = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
mxArray* LENGTH = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);

double* psample = mxGetPr(SAMPLE);
double* plength = mxGetPr(LENGTH);

for (int iii = 0; iii < arraysize1; iii++){
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < arraysize1; jjj++){

        if (!ep) {
            if (!(ep = engOpen(""))) {
                AfxMessageBox(L"Can't start MATLAB engine");
                //return -1;
            }
            engOutputBuffer(ep, buffer, 255);

            sprintf(cmd, "cd '%s';", directory);
            engEvalString(ep, cmd);

        }


        *psample = samplerate[iii];
        *plength = length[jjj];

        engPutVariable(ep, "L2", LENGTH);
        engPutVariable(ep, "h2", SAMPLE);

        sprintf(CALL, "isinvpendstab(L2,h2)");

        sprintf(cmd, "X=%s;", CALL);
        engEvalString(ep, cmd);


        double resultc[256];
        double *presultc;
        mxArray *resultm;

        if ((resultm = engGetVariable(ep, "X")) == NULL) {
            AfxMessageBox(L"Oops! You didn't create a variable X.\n\n");
        }
        else {
            double d = mxGetScalar(resultm);
            ofstream myfile("outputmatlab.txt");


            resultc[i] = d;

            myfile << setw(14) << resultc[i]<<endl;

            i++;

        }

    }


}


WCHAR wbuf[256];
swprintf(wbuf, L"successful");
AfxMessageBox(wbuf);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the question is a nice example that shows how to interact with Matlab from C++. And generally I think the code works pretty well.

The only problem is that the output file is overwritten in every iteration. So better open the file before the loop, and close it after the loop. 
Or open the file with the append parameter (`ofstream myfile("outputmatlab.txt", ios_base::app)`) in case there is a reason to open the file in every iteration.

I agree with oro777 that having the engOpen() in the loop does not look nice. However, since the engine is only opened if the engine pointer (ep) is 0, the engine will be opened only once so that should not be a problem.

Anyway, you should remember to close the file and the engine at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think you need to put engOpen() in your for loop, just launch the engine one time. After you are done with the engine, you have to close it using engClose(ep);